# How do multiple power increases and reductions affect this creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So, I have on my board [Chief of the Edge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChief%20of%20the%20Edge%5d) and [Herald of Dromoka](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHerald%20of%20Dromoka%5d). My opponent plays [Dovin Baan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDovin%20Baan%5d) and uses his first ability on Herald of Dromoka.

What is the attack of the Herald now? Does it first go to 0 and then have +1 from the Chief or does it first gain the buff and then go to 0 from Dovin Baan?

Answer (score 7):

**Herald of Dromoka winds up with a power of 0** because it is affected by -3 and +1 power simultaneously, which is a -2 modifier no matter which way it occurs.

The first thing to help clarify this is that *power can be in negative numbers.* See [Char-Rumbler](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChar-Rumbler%5d) for one of the only examples of cards with negative power. (It's got a ruling saying: "Yes, Char-Rumbler’s printed power is -1. While its power is -1 or 0, it simply deals no combat damage.")

Since power doesn't bottom out at 0 and can just keep going down into negative numbers, there's no actual difference either way you order it:

- If Dovin Baan applies first, the Herald's power is reduced to -1 then increased to 0.
- If Chief of the Edge applies first, the power is increased to 3 then reduced to 0.

Comment: 107.1b Most of the time, the Magic game uses only positive numbers and zero. You can’t choose a negative number, deal negative damage, gain negative life, and so on. However, it’s possible for a game value, such as a creature’s power, to be less than zero. If a calculation or comparison needs to use a negative value, it does so. If a calculation that would determine the result of an effect yields a negative number, zero is used instead, unless that effect sets a player’s life total to a specific value, doubles a player’s life total, or sets a creature’s power or toughness to a specific value.

Comment: Magic the gathering effects are like onions. They have layers.